# Intra class correlation coefficient equals 1 for both random effects

Tags: statistics, lme4

I am evaluating for clustering of two grouping variables that I may include as random effects in a glmm with other predictors. Both grouping variables are nested elements of the study design. The first is "Sample" (for context, each microbiological field sample we collected was processed in triplicate counts on agar plates) :

```
CephRes2 <- Merged_DF_Reduced_BestPlates_Analysis_Final %>% 
  glmer(ESBL_FOX_CEP_Count ~ 1 + (1 | Sample), family=poisson(link = "log"), data = .)
summary(CephRes2)
icc(CephRes2)
```

The second is "Site" (for context, each site we visited, we collected a microbiological sample from 3 different sources):

```
CephRes3 <- Merged_DF_Reduced_BestPlates_Analysis_Final %>% 
  glmer(ESBL_FOX_CEP_Count ~ 1 + (1 | Site), family = poisson(link = "log"), data = .)
summary(CephRes3)
icc(CephRes3)
```

The ICC for both groupings equals 1.000 without error or warning, but I am also concerned that I may be missing something important regarding over-fitting. We have n=296 total count observations, from 99 'Sample' (field samples) and 53 'Site' groups; we only have 3 observations/levels from each 'sample' grouping and 2-3 levels for each Site grouping.

Usually, a high ICC warrants a random effect from that grouping variable in a model, but I am suspicious of moving forward because I know that overfitting can occur without enough data. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to interpret these results? Does anyone have suggestions for specifying random effects for a dataset like mine?

Please let me know if I can provide more context or information.

Here are two images of my outputs.  [ICC calculation for Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05NSF.png)
[ICC calculation for Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbsIE.png)